# Incorrect count value returned by the count function from the HTML browser database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

I just want to count the number of rows in the database, but it seems to be showing wrong values. To be precise, it always returns 1.
The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="dt">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="INSERT DATE">
    <input type="button" id="count" value="count">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var db = openDatabase("Dates", "1.0", "Test Dates", 200000);     
var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Date (sampledate DATE)";    
var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Date (sampledate) VALUES (?)";    
var countcomm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Date";    
var dataset;    

db.transaction(function(xd)
          {
    xd.executeSql(createStatement, []);
});

$(document).ready(function()  
{
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#submit").click(insertdate);
    $("#count").click(countdates);
});

function countdates()
{
db.transaction(function(xd)
              {
                xd.executeSql(countcomm, [], function (xd, result) {
                dataset = result.rows;
                alert(dataset.length);
        });
    });
}

function insertdate()
{
    var datetemp = $("#dt").val();
    db.transaction(function(xd)
              {
        xd.executeSql(insertStatement, [datetemp])
    })
    alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHkW.png)

As you can see in the alert that the count value it shows is 1 whereas it is expected to show 5 since there are 5 rows in the database

Comment: You need to look at the value *in the row*.  Any `count()` query with no `group by` is always going to return one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var countcomm = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Date";` to `var countcomm = "SELECT * FROM Date";`